# Pass information from client and MVC through Request globally for any Web API calls

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-middleware

I need to pass information from client and MVC through Request globally for any Web API calls that was made from MVC and UI.

I use HttpClient to make WebApi calls.

I use Middleware from MVC to intercept the Web API calls to add some custom headers in the Request as shown below. Below is my sample code.

```
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Request.Headers.Add("AuditInfo", "xxxxxxxxxx");
        await next.Invoke(context);
    }
```

When I check the request headers from WebApi, I am not able to see headers that I added in the Middleware.

Note : I am able to add the headers successfully and view it from WebApi  Request, if I add the headers while creating HttpClient as shown below. But I want to add this functionality globally for the Web API request that’s been made from MVC and UI.

### Code To Add headers and call API:

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("AuditInfo", "xxxxxxxxxx");

client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:62239/");

HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/test/").Result;

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
string jsonResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, you want to use middleware in mvc application to handle `HttpClient`. Middleware is for handling incoming requests, not outgoing requests. Since `HttpClient` request is a outgoing request you can't use middleware to handle it.

> But I want to add this functionality globally for the Web API request

You can simply create a `HttpClient` factory class for this:

```
public interface IHttpClientFactory
{
    HttpClient GetClient();
}
public class HttpClientFactory : IHttpClientFactory
{
    public HttpClient GetClient()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("AuditInfo", "xxxxxxxxxx");

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:62239/");
        return client;
    }
}
```

And then whenever you need get and use it:

```
private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
....
var client = _httpClientFactory.GetClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/test/").Result;

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) string jsonResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```